# Inserting an entity with TenantId in abp.io framework

Tags: c#, multi-tenant, abp

I have an entity below that, when I create, inserts with `TenantId` `null`. Is it necessary to use `CurrentTenant.Id` to set `TenantId` manually?

```
public class Hall : AuditedAggregateRoot<Guid>, IMultiTenant
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Explanation { get; set; }
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't inherit from `AsyncCrudAppService`, then it is necessary to set `TenantId` yourself.

```cs
protected void TryToSetTenantId(TEntity entity)
{
    var tenantId = CurrentTenant.Id;

    if (!tenantId.HasValue)
    {
        return;
    }

    var propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty(nameof(IMultiTenant.TenantId));

    if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
    {
        propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, tenantId, null);
    }
}
```

ABP Framework (abp.io) does not limit the case where you may want to create a host or other tenant entity within a tenant scope.

References:

- [abpframework/abp#1130 (comment 493737582)](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1130#issuecomment-493737582)
- [abpframework/abp#1360 (comment 505299635)](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/1360#issuecomment-505299635)

Comment: Thanks for reply, The service implements CrudAppService also.

Comment: @EmrahKONDUR Are you calling the app service as a tenant user?

Comment: I have already logged in via Admin then I changed to tenant user, It's worked. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you @aaron